# How can I write this LINQ query as a Lambda expression?

Tags: c#, linq

Here's my query expression:

```
ddCourse.DataSource = (from c in db.COURSE_MASTERs
                       orderby c.COURSE_TITLE 
                       select new { c.COURSE_ID, c.COURSE_TITLE }).ToList();
```

Just for the sake of knowledge, I'd like to know how to write this as a Lambda expression.  Here is what I have so far:

```
ddCourse.DataSource = db.COURSE_MASTERs
                        .OrderBy(c => c.COURSE_TITLE)
                        .Select(c => {c.COURSE_ID, c.COURSE_TITLE})
                        .ToList();
```

Of course, what I have is wrong so I'm hoping that someone can help point me in the right direction?  Again, the only reason I'm doing this is for the sake of knowledge.

Comment: Read (and post) the error messages. In this case the "red squiggle" would have given a good indication of where/what the issue was. (I'm really not sure why this is getting voted up :>)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot `new`:

```
.Select(c => new { c.COURSE_ID, c.COURSE_TITLE })
```

Comment: That was it!  My thanks!  I'll mark the answer as soon a the timer is up.  I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Missing the `new` keyword:

```
ddCourse.DataSource = db.COURSE_MASTERs
  .OrderBy(c => c.COURSE_TITLE)
  .Select(c => new {c.COURSE_ID, c.COURSE_TITLE})
  .ToList();
```